# Asus ROG driver for ubuntu

Tags: drivers, asus

I bought an Asus ROG Strix without operating system, and I've just installed Ubuntu.
The keyboard led are blinking, there is a way to keep it on without blinking?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by installing rogauracore: https://github.com/wroberts/rogauracore